# C 2D Array of strings causes a segmentation fault outside of the function it is declared

Tags: c, string, memory-management, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

The code in question is intended to load data from a txt file that will be used later on to play a console version of Conways Game of Life. The datatype is a 2D array of strings so that further iterations of the game of life can be stored in order to check for oscillating patterns. It passes the array to the "readworld" function by reference. It loads the number of iterations, width and height of the future array from the top of the text file.

The issue with this code is that it loads from the text file and saves it successfully inside the "loadWorld" function. This is proved by printing the output at the end of the function. But when that same array is accessed in the "main" function, a segmentation fault occurs at the first element.

This is weird because memory allocated by malloc is supposed to be allocated on the heap and thus assessable for other functions unless I'm missing something...

Im not sure if I should post the text file but if I should, leave a comment and it will be posted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Notes
Compiled file with MinGW 4.7.2.
The first line of the text file contains the number of columns, rows and iterations to perform of GOL.
An x in the text file represents a live cell whilst a space represents a dead cell.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readworld(char ***,int *,int *,int*);

int main(){
    int rows,columns,ticks,repetition,count,count2;
    char ***world;
    readworld(world,&rows,&columns,&ticks);
    printf("Rows: %i Columns: %i Ticks: %i\n",rows,columns,ticks);
    for(count = 1; count < rows-1; count++){
        //Segmentation fault occurs here.                       
        printf("%s",world[0][count]);
    }

    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;

}

void readworld(char ***world,int *rows,int *columns,int *ticks){
    FILE *f;
    int x,y;


    //Load the file
    f=fopen("world.txt","r");
    //Load data from the top of the file. 
    //The top of the file contains number of rows, number of columbs and number of iterations to run the GOL
    fscanf(f,"%i %i %i\n", rows, columns, ticks);

    printf("%d %d %d\n",*rows, *columns, *ticks);

    *columns=*columns+2;  //Includes new line and end of line characters
    world=(char***) malloc(*ticks*sizeof(char**));      //makes an array of all the grids

    for (y=0;y<*ticks;y++){

        world[y]=(char**) malloc(*rows * sizeof(char*));    //makes an array of all the rows

        for (x=0;x<*rows;x++){
            world[y][x]=(char*) malloc( *columns * sizeof(char));   //makes an array of all the collumns
        }
    }

    for (y=0;y<*rows;y++){
        fgets(world[0][y],*columns,f);  //fills the array with data from the file
    }
    //Correctly prints the output from the textfile here
    for (y = 0 ; y < *rows; y++) 
            printf("%s",world[0][y]);
}
```

Comment: You are passing a **copy** of `world` into the `readworld` function...

Comment: The triple pointer burns us... it BURNS US!

Comment: You'll need to pass the triple pointer by pointer ... or by reference, so you can reassign it.

Comment: @Dukeling: Question is tagged C, so I guess no references...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh right, I always forget that about C.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an object into a function, your computer creates a copy of that object and assigns it the same value. Any changes that function makes to the copy object won't be applied to the original object.

Hence, in your testcase (which should look like this)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void readworld(char ***);

int main(){
    char ***world;
    readworld(world);
}

void readworld(char ***world){
    world = malloc(42);
}
```

`world` within `main` is unaffected by the change made to the (different) `world` within `readworld`. You'd want to pass a pointer to `world` to `readworld` and modify the object pointed to, similarly to `rows`, `columns` and `ticks` if you want the changes to be visible beyond `readworld`.

```
int main(void) {
    ...
    readworld(&world,&rows,&columns,&ticks);
    ...
}

void readworld(char ****world, int *rows, int *columns, int *ticks){
    ...
    *world = malloc(42);
    ...
}
```